# WebApi 2 [POST] method receives wrong values

Tags: jquery, vb.net, post, webapi

I'm trying to pass a javascript object to my POST method in VB.NET WebApi 2 but the issue is while the passed object is the following

[image]

WebApi receive all values as 0 and that happen with each value even if negozio is set to 5 it will still receive 0, here you can see that cassa values are 0 and 0 while in passed object they were 1 and 5

[image]

Could the issue be related to the model? If so how can i fix it to get right values?
Here is my model in VB.NET

```
Public Class Cfg

    Public Property negozio As List(Of NEGOZI)
    Public Property cassa As List(Of CASSE)
    Public Property operatore As List(Of OPERATORI)

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub


    Public Sub New(ByVal negozio As List(Of NEGOZI), ByVal cassa As List(Of CASSE), ByVal operatore As List(Of OPERATORI))
        Me.negozio = negozio
        Me.cassa = cassa
        Me.operatore = operatore
    End Sub

    Public Class NEGOZI

        Public Property NPV As Integer

        Public Sub New()
        End Sub


        Public Sub New(ByVal NPV As Integer)
            Me.NPV = NPV
        End Sub

    End Class

    Public Class CASSE

        Public Property CS As Integer

        Public Sub New()
        End Sub


        Public Sub New(ByVal CS As Integer)
            Me.CS = CS
        End Sub

    End Class

    Public Class OPERATORI

        Public Property OP As Integer

        Public Sub New()
        End Sub


        Public Sub New(ByVal OP As Integer)
            Me.OP = OP
        End Sub

    End Class

End Class
```

Here is the controller

```
<HttpPost()>
<Route("post")>
Public Sub PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal config As Cfg)
    MsgBox(config.negozio(0).NPV)
End Sub
```

And here is my method where i call $.post after each checkbox value has changed

```
$(".nav").on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function () {
    var config = {
        negozio: [],
        cassa: [],
        operatore: []
    };


    $(this).siblings('div').children('ul')
        .find("input[type='checkbox']")
        .prop('checked', this.checked);

    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function () {
        const npv = $(this).attr('data-npv');
        const cs = $(this).attr('data-cs');
        const op = $(this).attr('data-op');

        if (npv != null)
            config.negozio.push(npv);

        if (cs != null)
            config.cassa.push(cs);

        if (op != null)
            config.operatore.push(op);
    });
    console.log(config)
    $.post("api/prodotti/post/", config);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that i was passing values npv, cs, op without key, by adding it all works as it have,

So the javascript code changed as the following:

```
$(".nav").on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function () {
    var config = {
        negozio: [],
        cassa: [],
        operatore: []
    };


    $(this).siblings('div').children('ul')
        .find("input[type='checkbox']")
        .prop('checked', this.checked);

    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function () {
        const npv = $(this).attr('data-npv');
        const cs = $(this).attr('data-cs');
        const op = $(this).attr('data-op');

        if (npv != null)
            config.negozio.push({ NPV: npv });

        if (cs != null)
            config.cassa.push({ CS: cs });

        if (op != null)
            config.operatore.push({ OP: op });
    });
    console.log(config)
    $.post("api/prodotti/post/", config);
});
```